# Clear Deep linking react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent

I am using deep linking for SSO from my another app. I have used `Linking` for this purpose on root container and I have added `<intent-filter>` for the app linking.

But the problem is if I come back on the same screen the `Linking.getInitialURL()` gives same URL. How can I clear the Linking after used for signing in.

My AndroidManfest.xml used for deep linking.

```
<intent-filter android:excludeFromRecents="true">
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data android:scheme="costsfirst.applinking" />
</intent-filter>
```